# Tomcat 9 throwing - rg.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource

Tags: tomcat9

02-Feb-2022 16:35:23.846 WARNING [http-nio-9020-exec-442] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
02-Feb-2022 16:35:23.870 WARNING [http-nio-9020-exec-442] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
02-Feb-2022 16:35:23.975 WARNING [http-nio-9020-exec-442] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
02-Feb-2022 16:35:27.468 WARNING [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/classes/] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
02-Feb-2022 16:35:27.518 WARNING [http-nio-9020-exec-452] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/audio-cassettes-to-cd/index.html] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
02-Feb-2022 16:35:27.518 WARNING [http-nio-9020-exec-452] org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/audio-cassettes-to-cd/index.htm] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: tomcat 9 printing this log in catalina.log contniously 


org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/] to the cache for web application [] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache